# Help with understanding a commutative diagram/linear maps and writing matrices from them

Tags: linear-algebra

Denote by $P_n$ the set of polynomials in $t$ with real coefficients and degree at most $n$.

1) Let:
\begin{align}
p_1 &= 1 + 2t + 3t^2\\
p_2 &= t + 2t^2\\ 
p_3 &= t_2
\end{align}

> Are $p_1$, $p_2$, and $p_3$ linearly independent? Why?

2) Let $D: P_2 \to P_2$ be the linear map such that $D(1) = 0$, $D(t) = 1$, and $D(t^2) = 2t$.

> Find the kernel and range of $D$. What is the rank of $D$?

I have the answer, as attached in a picture, but I'm struggling to understand part 2. Where does the commutative square come from, and especially how did they come up with the columns of $A$?

Thank you for your help!

[Image of question and answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcoPs.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns of $A$ come from the way that $D$ operates on the basis vectors.

We have a basis in $(1, t, t^2)$, and we see that $D(1) = 0$, $D(t)=1$, and $D(t^2) = 2t$. $A$ is just the matrix representing $D$ in this basis.

The commutative square just comes from the fact that any degree-$3$ or less polynomial with real coefficients can be represented as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (according to the basis I described above) and hence any linear transformation (such as $D$) between those polynomials must also get transported by the representation functor over to a matrix (giving a linear transformation between vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$).

Comment: So does each column of A correspond to an element of the basis? Like the 2nd column corresponds to D(t) = 1?

Comment: @Br915 Yeah. The first column is what polynomial $1$ gets mapped to by $D$ (in this case, $0$, which we represent with the vector $(0,0,0)$). Similarly, the second column is what polynomial $t$ gets mapped to by $D$ (in this case, $1$, which is the vector $(1,0,0)$). The third column tells us which polynomial $t^2$ gets mapped to by $D$ (which is $2t$, and we represent this by $(0,2,0)$).